Index PDF files in Coveo
We need to index content of PDF document in Coveo, so we can match the user search against pdf content and provide the pdf url in the search results.
We have a PDF Viewer component on a web page to display the pdf file, we are using Coveo Platform for search and Sitemap source to index our pages so Coveo can crawl pages using sitemap.xml file.
How do we get the pdf media url in to sitemap.xml file ?
How do we enable pdf content indexing in Coveo ?

There is few steps below by which you can achive this,

Add PDF Media URLs to Sitemap First, ensure that your PDF files are accessible via URLs. Then, update your sitemap.xml file to include these URLs. Here is an example of how to include PDF URLs in your sitemap.xml file:


<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
   <url>
      <loc>https://www.yourwebsite.com/files/sample1.pdf</loc>
      <lastmod>2024-01-01</lastmod>
      <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
      <priority>0.8</priority>
   </url>
   <url>
      <loc>https://www.yourwebsite.com/files/sample2.pdf</loc>
      <lastmod>2024-01-01</lastmod>
      <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
      <priority>0.8</priority>
   </url>
   <!-- Add more PDF URLs as needed -->
</urlset>



Configure Coveo Sitemap Source Ensure that your Coveo Sitemap source is correctly configured to crawl the sitemap.xml file where you added the PDF URLs:


Log in to Coveo Platform.
Go to the Content tab and select Sources.
Add a new source and select Sitemap as the source type.
Provide the URL to your sitemap.xml file.
Configure the crawling settings as needed.



Enable PDF Content Indexing in Coveo Coveo can index the content of PDFs, but you need to ensure that the appropriate connectors and configurations are in place:
Coveo usually comes with out-of-the-box support for parsing PDF content. Ensure that the feature is enabled.
In the Coveo Administration Console, go to the Configuration tab and ensure that the File Parsing Service is enabled and configured.
Configure Fields and Mappings:
Ensure that the fields used for indexing PDF content are correctly mapped. This includes fields like documentbody or similar that Coveo uses to store the content of the PDF.
You can customize the field mappings in the Fields section under Content.
Test and Validate:
Once everything is set up, reindex your Sitemap source and validate that the PDFs are being indexed correctly.
Use the Coveo Query Editor to test searches and ensure that the content of the PDFs is searchable.

Integrate PDF Viewer Component Since you have a PDF Viewer component on your webpage, ensure that the URLs displayed by this component match the URLs in the sitemap. When a user clicks on a search result, the PDF Viewer should open the corresponding PDF.


This information collected from various source and refer the documention, usually I did not try for that as It was never need but you can try this.
